# Fireworks animation using pages instead of states

Tags: animation, adobe, fireworks

I am using Adobe Fireworks 5.1 for Mac and I am trying to make a banner animation.
I know how to make a normal animation using multiple states, however, I need to hotspot each slide of the banner animation to point to a different URL.
I am trying to do this without using Flash because Fireworks is easier to use.